# Display duplicate column with increasing count in separate column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to increase count in `count` column one by one if the same `Id` is found  in records.

Don't consider about auto increment of `Id`.

MySQL version 8.0 and you can order by `name` column.

I tried but not getting any solution.

My table `Employee` looks like this

```
       +------+-------+-------+
       | Id   | Name  |address|
       +------+-------+-------+
       | 111  | Sam   |  xyz  |
       | 112  | Mike  |  xyz  |
       | 113  | Carol |  xyz  |
       | 113  | Bob   |  xyz  |
       | 113  | John  |  xyz  |
       | 116  | Adam  |  xyz  |
       | 116  | David |  xyz  |
       +------+-------+-------+
```

I want to run sql query which will give output like this, if `Id` is same increase count

```
    +------+-------+-------+
    | Id     | Name  | count |
    +------+-------+-------+
    | 111    | Sam   |  1    |
    | 112    | Mike  |  1    |
    | 113    | Carol |  1    |
    | 113    | Bob   |  2    |
    | 113    | John  |  3    |
    | 114    | Adam  |  1    |
    | 114    | David |  2    |
    +------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: If you have MySQL 8+ use window function. If you have MySQL 5+ use user-defined variable. If MyISAM is safe use secondary AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: Your `count` field makes no sense until ORDER BY is specified. Your source data have no such ordering which is easy to see/understand. Do not refer on the physical order of records - it NOT exists.

Comment: hi @Akina, see my edited question again. Actually i want record from employee table . if id is same i want count of that id with increament of one in separate column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function can *generate* your current `count` column, more or less:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    Name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Name) count
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    Id,
    Name;
```

Note that `ROW_NUMBER` requires MySQL 8+.